# I am very new to java. Getting an error message listed below

Tags: java

```
package StreetKing;

import java.awt.Color;

public class TrffcLgt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /**
        * This class represents a simple implementation of a stoplight.
        * The client can determine the current state of the stoplight by
        * calling stoplight.getState() and change it to the next color
        * in the sequence (GREEN -> YELLOW -> RED -> GREEN) by calling
        * stoplight.advance().
        */
        public class Stoplight {
        /** Constant indicating the color GREEN */
        public static final Color GREEN = Color.GREEN;
        /** Constant indicating the color YELLOW */
        public static final Color YELLOW = Color.YELLOW;
        /** Constant indicating the color RED */
        public static final Color RED = Color.RED;
        /**
        * Creates a new Stoplight object, which is initially GREEN.
        */
        public Stoplight() {
            state = 0;
        }

        /**
        * Returns the current state of the stoplight.
        * @return The state of the stoplight (GREEN, YELLOW, or RED)
        */
        public Color getState() {
            switch (state) {
                case 0: return GREEN;
                case 1: return YELLOW;
                case 2: return RED;
                default: return null; /* Can't occur but required by Java */
             }
        }

        /**
        * Advances the stoplight to the next state.
        */
        public void advance() {
            state = (state + 1) % 3;
        }

        /* Private instance variable */
        private int state;
        }
    }

}
```

Getting an error message as "Illegal modifier for the local class Stoplight; only abstract or final is permitted". What should be the solution for this?

Comment: take `Stoplight` and declare it outside your `main` method - then, you can create an instance of it via `Stoplight sl = new Stoplight();` from inside the `main` method

Comment: Done but still getting error "It is giving an error that "The public type Stoplight must be defined in its own file"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have inappropriately tried to declare the class `Stoplight` *inside* a method (your `main` method).

This is technically allowed (Yes it is!  It is a *local class*) but if you declare a class in this context, you cannot declare it as `public`.  (Think about it.  The class declaration is intuitively only in scope within the method body.  So declaring it as `public` makes no sense.)

Having said that, it is *probably* not the right thing to do here.  A better solution would be to either move the `Stoplight` class into a separate file, or move it into the (abominally named) `TrrfcLgt` class, so that it is a nested class.  (If you do the latter, change it to `static` too ...)

Comment: After following what you have said.It is giving an error that "The public type Stoplight must be defined in its own file".

Comment: You've put it in the wrong place.  Either put the class in a separate file (the best idea) or put it **inside** the `TrffcLgt` class ... like I said above.

Comment: It is working now. Could you suggest me any website or book from where I should practice java questions.

Comment: That is an off-topic question.  I'm sure you can find something using Google.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `Stoplight` class definition outside your main method.